# How can i send multiple camera to one server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, rtsp, rtmp

How can i send all webcams to collect from one server.
For example:

there is pc_1, pc2, ..., pc_n they are sending camera view to some ubuntu server where i can connect with
`ssh name@ip_adress`

and all pc have a windows on them

- i looked [Sending live video frame over network in python opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988033/sending-live-video-frame-over-network-in-python-opencv) this but this worked only on localhost
- and secondly i looked this [Forward RTSP stream to remote socket (RTSP Proxy?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755281/forward-rtsp-stream-to-remote-socket-rtsp-proxy?noredirect=1&lq=1) but couldnt figure out how to do it on my situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each IPC is a RTSP server, it allows you to pull/play RTSP stream from it:

```
IPC ---RTSP--> Client(Player/FFmpeg/OBS/VLC etc.)
```

And because it's a internal IPC and its IP is intranet, so the client should in the same intranet, that's why it works only on `localhost` like.

Rather than pulling from the internet client which does not work, you could forward the stream to internet server, just like this:

```
IPC ---RTSP--> Client --RTMP--> Internet Server(SRS/Nginx etc.)
```

For example, use FFmpeg as a `Client` to do this, please replace the `xxx` by your internet server:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://user:password@ip" -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://xxx/live/stream
```

> Note: You could fastly deploy a internet server by [srs-droplet-template](https://github.com/ossrs/srs-droplet-template) in 3 minutes, without any cli or knowledge about media server.

Then you could play the stream by any client and any protocol, like PC/H5 by HTTP-FLV/HLS/WebRTC, mobile iOS/Android by HTTP-FLV/HLS, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565)

Comment: so that solution is realy good i actually tried before you answered it just different way but here is the problem now that i cant see the stream that i am sending to the nginx. for example ffmpeg -i "rtsp://user:password@ip" -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://xxx/live/stream i am using similar to this code line it starts to stream but i cant see any video or i cant see on http on the server

Comment: update: i manage to send video but when i do that i have to make an ssh tunnel connection with client and server for port 1935 but i see u use only one code like this to send; ffmpeg -i "rtsp://user:password@ip" -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://xxx/live/stream but i couldnt find what am i gonna put in that xxx is that a ip adress of the server or anything else sorry for my ignorance i am new at servers and streaming stuff

Comment: The `xxx` is your RTMP media server IP address, or domain name.

Comment: thank u so much dude i have an issue that servers port doenst open for 1935 so i couldnt sen the video when i open it video was sent good, but right know i am having an issue for latency but right know screen is crystal clear and thank u for answer